# Using writekml in stata to create maps in google earth

Tags: kml, google-earth, stata

I'm trying to use `writekml` in stata to create a `kml` map that can open in Google earth. I have the exact geographic coordinates of the places I need to map and they're stored under variable headers "latitude" and "longitude." The command I run is:

```
writekml, filename(xyzmap) plcategory(village_types)
```

The file is exporting but its showing up blank and and none of the markers are showing in google earth.

Note:

1. I've created maps using `shapefiles` but i want the ones in Google maps because of the greater detail
2. I've been able to manually convert an xls file containing the latitudes and longitudes to `kml` and then opening it with Google earth so I definitely know the coordinates are fine.

Comment: I'd write to the author of the program (which is on SSC) directly. I don't know anything about the details here but programs of this kind are very sensitive to changes in Google set-ups.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I'll do that!